# Table of contents: Dots and title

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

- I want to remove the dots of the table of content (toc), so i used:

  ```
  \makeatletter \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} \makeatother
  ```

  but it doesn’t work…
- How can I remove the title (name) of the toc?

I’m using `memoir` class and XeLaTeX.

Comment: Related: [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994/5764)

Answer (score 8):

- You need to use

  ```
  \renewcommand{\cftsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}
  ```

  in order to remove the dots for `\section` titles in the ToC. Or, in general,

  ```
  \renewcommand{\cftKdotsep}{\cftnodots}
  ```

  for the sectional unit `K`. For removing *all* dots the easiest way is to redefine the dot used to be empty: `\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}`. See chapter **9 Contents Lists** (p 164) of the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).
- You can change `\contentsname`. It will still be set as a chapter though. And you would most likely use `\tableofcontents*` to have it removed from the ToC itself.

Here's a short minimal example highlighting the above:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\renewcommand{\cftsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}% Remove dots for section
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}% Remove \tableofcontents' title/name
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\chapter{Last chapter}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi !
Thanks for your answer.
· For the dots, it works perfectly

· I tried

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

and I found there was a problem with the package

    \usepackage[french]{babel}

So I don’t know if I should remove french babel, or is there an other solution ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\cftnodots` is just the value 2000, so `\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2000}` may also be enough, since all of the dots settings in the toc referes back to this one