# How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?

Tags: naming

I'd like to modify the names used to typeset some of my document elements. For example, the caption of `figure` floats should change from "Figure" to "Fig.", and my `\tableofcontents` sectioning heading shouldn't read "Contents", but "Table of Contents". How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{foo}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 253, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not you use a language package like  [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) or [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia).

### Without `babel` or `polyglossia`

Names like "Figure" and "Contents" are stored in macros like `\figurename` and `\contentsname`, i.e., to change them, you have to change the definition of the respective macros. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
```

Here's a list of the "name macros" (and their default meaning) defined by the LaTeX standard classes `article`, `book`, and `report`:

- `\abstractname` [only `article`, `report`]: Abstract
- `\appendixname`: Appendix
- `\bibname` [only `book`, `report`]: Bibliography
- `\chaptername` [only `book`, `report`]: Chapter
- `\contentsname`: Contents
- `\figurename`: Figure
- `\indexname`: Index
- `\listfigurename`: List of Figures
- `\listtablename`: List of Tables
- `\partname`: Part
- `\refname` [only `article`]: References
- `\tablename`: Table

Other classes and packages may define additional "name macros"; here are some you're likely to come up against (plus their source):

- `\acronymname` [`glossaries`]: Acronyms
- `\alsoname` [`makeidx`]: see also
- `\ccname` [`letter`]: cc
- `\enclname` [`letter`]: encl
- `\glossaryname` [`glossaries`]: Glossary
- `\headtoname` [`letter`]: To
- `\lstlistingname` [`listings`]: Listing *(the environment)*
- `\lstlistlistingname` [`listings`]: Listings *(the "List of")*
- `\nomname` [`nomencl`]: Nomenclature
- `\notesname` [`endnotes`]: Notes
- `\pagename` [`letter`]: Page
- `\prefacename` [`babel`]: Preface
- `\proofname` [`amsthm`]: Proof
- `\seename` [`makeidx`]: see *(misdefined as "see also" in the AMS classes)*
- `\seeonlyname` [AMS classes]: see

### With `babel`

There is a specific macro to redefine (or define) captions, as shown:

```
\setlocalecaption{english}{contents}{Table of Contents}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{abstract}{ملخص}
\setlocalecaption{ancientgreek}{also}{ὃρα ὡσαύτως}
```

The first argument is the language, the second argument is a shortened name of the caption, so that `contents` defines `\contentsname`, and the last is the string. You shouldn’t add any macros to switch the direction or the script, because `babel` takes care of that. There are other ways to modify the captions, but this is the recommended one.

### With `polyglossia`

The same principles as sec. “Without `babel` or `polyglossia`” apply – with one crucial difference: for every language, "name macros" must be redefined in the argument of `\addto\captions<language>` (instead of a simple `\renewcommand`). That is, for the English language, you'd have to add the following to your preamble (after loading `polyglossia`):

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
}
```

Don’t forget to add a `%` at the end of line after each redefinition.

### Changing "Bibliography" and "References" with `biblatex`

The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package is an exception to the rule: It uses "bibliography strings" for (among other things) the headings of bibliographies, so redefining `\bibname` or `\refname` won't work (whether you use `babel` or not). To rename both "Bibliography" and "References" to "Works Cited" for the English language, add the following to your preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {Works Cited},
  references = {Works Cited},
}
```

### Afterword

"Name macros" should *only* contain the string to be printed. *Don't* add formatting instructions like `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{20pt}{\Huge Table of Contents}}` – they may "work" in the document body, but are likely to play havoc with, e.g., headers and bookmarks. To change the formatting of the "Contents" heading, either redefine `\tableofcontents` as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83383/510) or, if you want your changes to apply to all sectioning headings, have a look at the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. For captions, the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package offers a host of customization possibilities.

Comment: @lockstep -- there are some additional "names" in the ams document classes, as well as one significant conflict.  the conflict: `\seename` was badly misdefined in the original release (to be "see also"), but since it was too late to fix it by the time someone complained, `\seeonlyname` ( = "see") was added to provide the correct value.  is it worth adding this to the list?

Comment: For some reason, `\addto\captionsbritish` works for me in changing 'Bibliography' to 'References' even in the presence of the babel package. This contrasts [lockstep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s answer but I can't really explain why or how it happened.

Comment: Please note that as of Babel Ver. 3.15, the `\addto` routine is obsolete for *some* languages (French, Spanish, and others). The new way is `\renewcommand\frenchfigurename{Figure}`, where `french` is your language and `figure` is to be replaced with the float/element in question.

Comment: I'm still getting "cuadro" instead of "tabla" in Spanish with cleveref and polyglossia.

Answer (score 65):

In addition to the answer of lockstep:

### With KOMA-Script

KOMA-Script (to be correct, package `scrbase`, which is called in the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook` and `scrlttr2` and in the KOMA-Script package `scrextend`) defines two macros for *naming* or *renaming* LaTeX names:

```
\newcaptionname{language}{LaTeX name}{new content}   % new name
\renewcaptionname{language}{LaTeX name}{new content} % renew existing name
```

Here is a example for German language:

```
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhalt}           %Table of contents
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}    %Figures
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listtablename}{Tabellen}        %Tables
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}               %Figure
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}                %Table
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\bibname}{Literatur}             %Bibliography
  \newcaptionname{ngerman}{\lstlistlistingname}{Quelltexte} %Table of listings 
  \newcaptionname{ngerman}{\lstlistingname}{Quelltext}      %Listing
```

You can see, that `\renewcaptionname` renames an existing LaTeX name like `\contentsname`. The macro `\newcaptionname` defines a new LaTeX name for KOMA-Script like `\lstlistingname` (because `\lstlistingname` is not defined in KOMA-Script).

If you use package `babel` together with KOMA-Script it is better to use the mechanism of KOMA-Script instead of `babel`s because KOMA-Script has a better verification.

**Update:**

With loading the package `scrextend` (see chapter 16, file `scrguien.pdf`, `texdoc scrguien`) you can use some KOMA-Script features with non KOMA-Script classes. For example `scrextend` loads `scrbase`.

The following MWE shows, that it works nice, and that loading of `scrextend` does not redefine the default font for titles in standard classes: it stays in serif (roman), while in KOMA-Script the default is sans-serif. Compile first with the commented line, then uncomment and compile again. Compare the titles of the table of contents.

```
\listfiles                  % to check if scrbase is loaded
\documentclass{article}     % original class
\usepackage{scrextend}      % allows some KOMA-Script features
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed for "blindtext"
\usepackage{blindtext}      % to create dummy text

% \renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Contents of ``Blindtext''} % renaming in KOMA-Script

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\blinddocument             % dummy text including several headings for TOC 
\end{document}
```

**Update 2:**

If you are not sure whether package `scrbase` is loaded or not you can test it with the command `\listfiles` (see first line in the MWE above). Command `\listfiles` prints in the `log` file a list with all called packages in your document. So if package `scrbase` is loaded you find it in this list (including used version), like this:

```
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
```

Comment: I've tried to use the `\renewcaptionname` command, but it does not appear to work. I copied the following line from the koma-script documentation (page 352):
`\renewcaptionname{USenglish}{\figurename}{fig.}`
but I get the following error:
Package scrbase Error: `\figurename' not defined at language `USenglish'.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 10):

For documents using `minted` package by [Konrad Rudolph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/42/konrad-rudolph), one can change the name of document elements as follows:

```
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Code-Snippet}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{List of program codes}
```

I added this answer as response to the comment of OP in [Reference Code snippet in latex using minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88311/reference-code-snippet-in-latex-using-minted/88317#comment191284_88317)

Answer (score 3):

Latex defaults References for article classes and Bibliographies for Reports. To change the default, add a title when you place your bibliography:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]
```

Comment: This is only valid for bibliographies done with biblatex. It does not answer the general question.

Comment: A (in my eyes at least) conceptually nicer solution for `biblatex` was already shown in the accepted answer by lockstep https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994/35864

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `article` documentclass this line will rename the name Title from your bib part from Bibliography to References.

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
```

Comment: Please note, this would only work, if package `babel` were loaded, and if `article` would use `bibname`. It does not, it uses `refname` which defaults to *References*.

Answer (score 0):

### 2024.1.12 updated

With `polyglossia`:

```
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\gappto\captionsenglish{
        \def\contentsname{Table of Contents}
        \def\listfigurename{List of Figures}
        \def\listtablename{List of Tables}
        }
% Note that this needs to be done after the respective language has been loaded with \setmainlanguage or \setotherlanguage.
```

Comment: How to do it with `polyglossia` was already explained before (in the main answer), and in fact your code is buggy (missing `%`’s) and relies on a TeX primitive, which is discouraged. (At least, your answer has made me discover that the explanation for `babel` was outdated.)

Comment: @Javier Bezos. I'm not using `babel`, `babel` is still updating. I just updated the latest command of `polyglossia` because I found that the command of `polyglossia` above is no longer working.

Comment: Of course `babel` is updating. Like LaTeX itself, Word, InDesign, Python, Chrome, MacOS, Windows or any other program actively maintained. Even `polyglossia` gets updates from time to time. That’s usually considered positive, not negative. BTW, I’ve just tested the code above and it works as expected, so I wonder if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Javier Bezos. I just tried your code again and it worked this time. But I remember that I didn't succeed at the time, and I don't know why, and then I looked at Page49 of the `polyglossia` manual to find the answer (which is my answer). So in order to avoid the mistake that I made in the future, I wrote this answer under this question. Just like the purpose of this community, we need to try to avoid going down the wrong path of repetition, just like standing on the shoulders of those who came before you, so that you can go further.