# babel and \contentsname, how to add extra customization?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, babel, naming

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{
\vspace{-8mm}
{\Huge Table of Contents}\vspace{-3mm}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm} \\[-4mm]
}
```

Using babel, I can get this code to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\addto\captionsenglish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
   %\vspace{10mm}
    {Table of Contents}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

but the second I try to add in that `\vspace` as a test, it fails. Any ideas how to fix this? Because I really want to add those options to the table of contents and I need the `babel` package as well.

Comment: `\contentsname` should contain only a string. Formatting changes to the table of contents should be made by modifying `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: hmm, but the first snippet of code I posted works as long as babel is not being used

Comment: It only "works" by accident. it would fail if \contentsname was used anywhere other than the main section title, for example page heading pdf bookmarks, ...

Comment: I see. What is the proper way to modify the spacing only around the ToC title then? And add the horizontal line just below the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way; modify the spacings to suit you.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \vspace*{-4mm}% reduce space before
  \noindent{\Huge\contentsname\par}%
  \vspace{2mm}% space between title and rule
  \hrule
  \vspace{2mm}% space below rule
  \@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
```

Don't add formatting instructions to `\contentsname`, which should only contain the string to print.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. This is exactly what I needed