# Why does the title of Glossary not change?

Tags: glossaries, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)

Consider the following MWE (it actually works `:P`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{dico3}{%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Dico}%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{longtable}{lll}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
\bfseries English & \bfseries Deutsch & \bfseries Français \\\endhead}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[2]{%
\glstarget{##1}{##2} & \glsentryuseri{##1} & \glsentryuserii{##1} \\}%
}

\glossarystyle{dico3}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{stg}{name=whatchacallit, description={\nopostdesc}, user1={Dingsbums, das}, user2={trucmuche, le}}
\glsaddall
\printglossary%[title=Dico] - UNCOMMENT THIS!
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am building a simple trilingual dictionary.

What puzzles me is that everything is fine, except that I need to uncomment the option `[title=Dico]` in the penultimate line to customize the title of my dictionary, although I used `\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Dico}` in the definition of my custom style. I don't get errors or warnings, neither from PDFLaTeX, nor from MakeIndex. Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Comment: With `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, you have to use `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Dico}}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr

Comment: @lockstep: Well I guess you can close it as a duplicate then. Thanks!