# titlesec: why is contents a section?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I've been playing around with the `titlesec` package combined with the `scrartcl` class. I find the headings titles of `scrartcl` a bit ugly, but I do like the fact that I can scale font sizes to 8pt.

Anyway that's not the point. I'm defining sections to be of the form

> 1.8 --- Sectionname.

But Contents is treated like a Section, and I am thus left with the most ugly

> --- Contents.

How to fix that? Am I using the `titlesec` package improperly?

MWE:

```
  \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block] % section
    {\scshape}
    {\thesection}
    {0pt}{\filcenter \hspace{.3em}---\hspace{.3em}}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}
    {0em} %left
    {0em} %before
    {1em} %after/below
    \begin{document}
     \tableofcontents
      \section{this a secti}
        ion.
      \end{document}
```

p.s. I also found myself doing things like `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\normalfont\scshape Abstract}`, am I a bad person?

Comment: I have edited the formatting of your question, I hope you don't mind; in particular, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: for anyone interested: instead of using a renewcommand for the abstractname, scrartcl comes with a \sectfont command, and one can renew that to uniformly change style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include the `---` as part of the numbered component of the sectional heading, not the text part. This way it will only show when the section is numbered:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\titleformat{\section}[block] % section
  {\scshape}
  {\thesection\hspace{.3em}---\hspace{.3em}}
  {0pt}{\filcenter}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0em} %left
  {0em} %before
  {1em} %after/below
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This a section}
This is some regular text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...why on earth didn't I think of that? by the way, do you happen to know if titlesec modifies the abstract title and whatnot? Just out of curiosity, as renewcommand does what I need it to do.

Comment: @carmelodevisu: [`titlesec.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty) does not reference `\abstractname`. I doubt it would *change* anything, since it's designed to give the user the ability to change that. Other packages might change this since their goal is to (say) language-specific. See, for example, [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764)