# Change name of listings

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)

I would change the name of listings but I don't know how to do. Instead to have

**Listings**

I would have it in my language:

**Lista dei codici**

What command I should use?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Lista dei codici}`.

Comment: I tried with that command but it doesn't work

Comment: OK, in that case you need to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates that it does not work.  It should start with `\documentclass`, and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: ok now it work...I checked well and it works but not with your command Peter Grill. this is the right command:
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Lista dei codici} but I explained me bad

Comment: Glad you were able to sort that out. What I had suggested would change the caption label. The one that worked for you is for the TOC which is what you wanted. For future reference, a really small [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)  would go a long way towards clarifying any possible misunderstandings.

Comment: you're right...I explained myself bad without reporting no example