# Reference Code snippet in latex using minted

Tags: cross-referencing, minted

I'm not really sure how to reference a code snippet in my text. I need also a caption for the code. The only working way I found is wrapping the minted in a figure. The problem is that I want to distinguish figures from code snippets..

```
\begin{figure} [ht]
\centering
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               numbersep=5pt,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=5mm]{sql}
natural join library.Book with amazon.Book as jointarge.BookCollection
with keep attributes library.Book.title
\end{minted}
\caption{A Caption}
\label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `listing` environment instead.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}[ht]
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               numbersep=5pt,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=5mm]{sql}
natural join library.Book with amazon.Book as jointarge.BookCollection
with keep attributes library.Book.title
\end{minted}
\caption{A Caption}
\label{lst:Listing}
\end{listing}
Listing \ref{lst:Listing} contains an example of a listing.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it normal, that the listing caption is above? And can I change the listing caption text "Listing" to "Code-Snippet"?

Comment: For the placement of the caption, just write `\caption{A caption}` after `\begin{listing}[ht]`. For changing the name of the 'listing caption', see my answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr/88330#88330 since this new request duplicates the question there.