# How to change caption from "Figure #:" to "Appendix #:"

Tags: floats, captions, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)

I was using `minipage` in LaTeX for my appendices in one of my English assignments, when I tried to do `minipage`, like so:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Appendix1-Modified}
    \caption{Nelson Mandela}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{5pt}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Appendix2}
    \caption{Qunu}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{5pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Appendix3}
    \caption{Mandela’s Prison Cell}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

In the actual appendices part, it always shows the picture, then the caption below it. Before the caption there's always a Figure #:, like so: "Figure 1: Nelson Mandela." I want to change the Figure 1: to Appendix 1:. Does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before the beginning of your `figure` - block, put

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix}
```

That will produce the desired output.

(Stylistically however, I would advise against doing this. An image on its own is rarely an appendix. I would rather have "Appendix 1" as a heading and then the image below that without an additional caption.)