# I would like to Change "Inhaltsverzeichnis" to "Contents"

Tags: table-of-contents, babel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)

In order to fix overruns I have used the following code:

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\sloppy
```

I found this code, along with many other useful tips on this site.

This code works great except for one small problem:

Instead of "Contents" I now have "Inhaltsverzeichnis."

Being that my book is in English, I would like to change this to "Contents"?

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps remove `ngerman`? Also have a look at [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr/82994#82994).

Comment: I tried that.The `/sloppy` command doesn't work without the ngerman

Comment: @Peter Grill The code in the link works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last listed language is used as default language. So if your book is in English and you have only some German text in it, then use the following intead:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
```

Also note that `\sloppy` is normally not recommended because it lowers the typesetting quality. Try to write your document first without it and only try it at the end if it is really needed.