# Change default text of numbered \part

Tags: babel, naming, parts

I have a large document with lector notes. And each lector I'm separating by `\part`. I would like to change the default numbering text from "part" to "Lecture".

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Figures/}}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    \input{titlingpage.tex}
    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter
    \part{Teknologiske forudsigelser}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{IFVT}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The language is Danish.

And as I said, I'm would like to change "Del" with "Grupperegning".

Comment: `\addto\captionsdanish{\renewcommand*{\partname}{Grupperegning}}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr

Answer (score 1):

Insert `\renewcommand\partname{Grupperegning}` immediately after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: As the OP uses `babel`, this will fail as soon as one switches to another language and then back to Danish.