# Creating a list of abbreviations with KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script, acronyms

I could not find the commands for creating a list of abbreviations with KOMA-Script. Could someone please tell it to me? Also could someone please tell me if the abbreviations list has to be at the beginning or at the end of the document? Thank you.

EDIT: I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[komastyle,automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%%% Abkuerzungen
\newacronym{hvs}{hvs}{human visual system}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents%
\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}%
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\parskip1.5ex 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungen}

%Text
Denn der menschliche Wahrnehmungsapparat, auch \gls{hvs} genannt, nimmt höherfrequente Bildinhalte schlechter wahr als niederfrequente.

\printglossary[title=Abk\"urzungen]
\end{document}
```

But I don't get the glossary to be shown at the end. What is wrong??? I used the perl script makeglossaries on command line.

Comment: KOMA-Script doesn't provide commands for this. Have a look at packages like [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro), [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) or [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: Abbreviation lists usually go at the front of a book unless endnotes are used; with endnotes, you should normally put them at the start of the endnotes section (where the abbreviations are most likely to be used).  However, if the main text also makes heavy use of acronyms or abbreviations, then you should put them at the start of the document, somewhere in the frontmatter.  A common order is something like: ToC, Preface, Acknowledgements, Abbreviations.

Comment: For what it's worth, I simply used a `longtable` for my last list of abbreviations: clean and simple --- but mine was used for abbreviations of citations that appeared in the footnotes.  `glossaries` is very useful for technical abbreviations.  Try `texdoc glossariesbegin` to get started.

Comment: A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user1234567890".

Comment: I’m a bit perplexed: I would have expected, that this small word “than” would provoke a fully different reaction.

Comment: I know ;-) ....

Comment: I meant it serious, not funny!

Comment: I’m not in the mood to help you, but let me assure you, your problem shown in the edited question is a problem of not proper reading the documentation. With the right setting I got a fine output.

Comment: What, your not in the mood to help me??? C'mon... why isn't \printglossary working?

Comment: Name yourself also here [Diddelmaus](http://www.golatex.de/profile,mode,viewprofile,u,3702.html) like in goLaTeX.de, where you asked the same question: [Ablürzungsverzeichnnis (glossaries) mit KOMA](http://www.golatex.de/abluerzungsverzeichnnis-glossaries-mit-koma-t10577.html) („Ablürzung? Was ist eine Ablürzung?“).

Answer (score 4):

*Written before substantial edit of question:*

KOMA-Script does not provide such commands. It is intended by the developer to use one of the packages out there in the wild. Which one fits best your needs you must find out yourself, take a look on some CTAN topics: [ab­brev](http://www.ctan.org/topic/abbrev), [acronym](http://www.ctan.org/topic/acronym) and [glos­sary](http://www.ctan.org/topic/glossary).

From my personal view I can only tell you that I successfully used `glossaries` together with KOMA-Script. There is also an related item in the `glossaries` FAQ: [How do I change the default translations provided by the glossaries package?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/faqs/glossariesfaq.html#translate) *(Thanks to Nicola Talbot for pointing me to this)*.

<sub>KOMA-Script provides commands for (re-)definition of language-dependent terms *(in documentation for recent version this is section 10.4)*, one of them is for glossary titles. See also [this answer to How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83021/9237)</sub>

---

*Answer to edit:*

Excerpt from documentation of glossaries, v3.04:

- Section 2.5 *(Package Options, Acronym options)*

  > **acronym** This creates a new glossary with the label acronym. This is equivalent to: `\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}` If the *acronym* package option is used, `\acronymtype` is set to acronym …
- Section 10 *(Displaying a glossary)*

  > `\printglossary[〈options〉]` where *〈options〉* is a *〈key〉=〈value〉* list of options. The following keys are available:
  >   **type** The value of this key specifies which glossary to print. If omitted, the default glossary is assumed. For example, to print the list of acronyms: `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]`
  >   **title** This is the glossary’s title (overriding the title specified when the glossary was defined).

So you simply should have written

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungen]
```

or used the KOMA-Script specific solution linked above for the title.

Comment: sry, but couldn't find the command for glossary titles with KOMA. You know which it is? this: \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\glossaryname}{Abkürzungen}  does not work.

Comment: In which language is your document to be set? Do you use `babel`? The command works exactly as given by you in a local file here. Did you by any chance forget to load `inputenc`?

Comment: @user1234567890 you could add `\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}` before loading `glossaries` to get the title translated automatically (into “Glossar”) or simply use `\printglossary[title=Abk\"urzungen]`