# How to change the caption name in the article class when using babel?

Tags: tables, captions, naming, french

I have used the following lines in my preamble

```
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

It still shows `Table 1 - ...` but I want it to be like `Tableau 1 - ...`

I tried to use `\addto\captionsfrench\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}` it didn't work either besides I am not using `babel`. What I don't understand is that it was working fine in another document using the `amsart` class, but it does not work in this document using the `article` class.

How can I change the name of the caption for tables in my document ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you writing in French *without* using `babel`? How do you manage hyphenation rules?

Comment: the ams article document class is `amsart`.  `\tablename` (and similar names) are defined there to permit straightforward language changes within the scope of the class, since most of the available caption packages make other changes that are not consistent or compatible with the desired ams style.  ams classes are designed to conform to ams publication specs, and if the style is changed by an author for a document submitted to the ams for publication, then there is extra work at ams changing it back to the canonical style.

Comment: Related: [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}` in the document preamble suffices.

However, writing in French without using the support of `babel` is quite dubious; here is an example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}

\hyphenpenalty=-9000 % just to show the problems with hyphenation
\tolerance=5000      % ditto

\begin{document}

Paris, commune la plus peuplée et capitale de la France, chef-lieu de la région 
Île-de-France et unique commune-département du pays, se situe au centre du Bassin 
parisien, sur une boucle de la Seine, entre les confluents avec la Marne en amont et avec 
l’Oise en aval. Ses habitants s’appellent les Parisiens. La ville est divisée en vingt 
arrondissements.

D’après le recensement de l’Insee, la commune de Paris comptait au 1\textsuperscript{er} 
janvier 2010 plus de 2,2 millions d'habitants. L'agglomération de Paris s’est largement 
développée au cours du xx\textsuperscript{e} siècle, rassemblant 10,4 millions d'habitants 
au 1\textsuperscript{er} janvier 2009, et son aire urbaine (l’agglomération et la couronne 
périurbaine) comptait environ 12,2 millions d'habitants au 1\textsuperscript{er} janvier 
2009. Elle est l'une des agglomérations européennes les plus peuplées.

La position de Paris, à un carrefour entre les itinéraires commerciaux terrestres et 
fluviaux et au cœur d’une riche région agricole, en a fait une des principales villes de 
France au cours du x\textsuperscript{e} siècle, avec des palais royaux, de riches abbayes 
et une cathédrale ; au cours du xii\textsuperscript{e} siècle, Paris devient un des 
premiers foyers en Europe pour l’enseignement et les arts. Le pouvoir royal se fixant dans 
cette ville, son importance économique et politique ne cesse de croître. Ainsi, au début 
du xiv\textsuperscript{e} siècle, Paris est la ville la plus importante de tout le monde 
chrétien. Au xviie siècle, elle est la capitale de la première puissance politique 
européenne, au xviii\textsuperscript{e} siècle le centre culturel de l’Europe et au 
xix\textsuperscript{e} siècle la capitale des arts et des plaisirs. Paris a donc joué un 
rôle politique et économique majeur dans l’histoire de l'Europe au cours du 
II\textsuperscript{e} millénaire. Symbole de la culture française, abritant de nombreux 
monuments, la ville attire dans les années 2000 près de trente millions de visiteurs par 
an. Paris occupe également une place prépondérante dans le milieu de la mode et du luxe ; 
c'est aussi la capitale la plus visitée au monde.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Des mots}
\fbox{Un tableau}
\end{table}

Le département de Paris avait, en 2005, un PIB par habitant de plus de 75 000 euros. La 
ville est, avec sa banlieue, la capitale économique et commerciale de la France, ainsi que 
sa première place financière et boursière. La région parisienne, avec un produit intérieur 
brut (PIB) de 558 milliards d'euros en 2008, est un acteur économique européen majeur. 
Elle est la 1\textsuperscript{re} région européenne en termes de PIB régional et 
6\textsuperscript{e} en termes de PIB par habitant PPA. La densité de son réseau 
ferroviaire, autoroutier et sa structure aéroportuaire, plaque tournante du réseau aérien 
français et européen, en font un point de convergence pour les transports internationaux. 
Cette situation résulte d’une longue évolution, en particulier des conceptions 
centralisatrices des monarchies et des républiques, qui donnent un rôle considérable à la 
capitale dans le pays et tendent à y concentrer les institutions. Depuis les années 1960, 
les politiques gouvernementales ont toutefois oscillé entre déconcentration et 
décentralisation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `babel` you can solve many problems, but *not* the problem with `\tablename` because of some glitches in the implementation of `babel` and `amsart`. So one has to do some extra work, unfortunately.

The same text with the preamble changed to

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\tablename}{{\scshape Tableau}}}

\hyphenpenalty=-9000 % just to show the problems with hyphenation
\tolerance=5000      % ditto

\begin{document}
```

will print like this

[image]

Notice the differences in hyphenation (but they're not the only differences). In both cases the caption is labeled "Tableau".

(Text from http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris)

Comment: Interesting. Note that in the second version (using `babel`), the caption name of the table is "Table", not "Tableau".

Comment: @Jubobs Hey! Why is that? I'll fix.

Comment: I had not seen that I was using the babel package somewhere in the preamble. Thanks a lot. I thought my problem was due to the fact that I was using the class "article" and not "amsarticle" like in the other document.

Answer (score 5):

The `caption` package is your friend there. You may also want to use the `prettyref` package for cross-referencing in French.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{tab}{Tableau~\ref{#1}}

\captionsetup{tablename=Tableau}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        un & deux & trois \\
        quatre & cinq & six\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bonjour la France!}
    \label{tab:nombres}
\end{table}
Dans le \prettyref{tab:nombres}, on compte de un \`{a} six.
\end{document}
```

EDIT (following barbara beeton's comment above):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\renewcommand\tablename{Tableau}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{tab}{\tablename~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        un & deux & trois \\
        quatre & cinq & six\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bonjour la France!}
    \label{tab:nombres}
\end{table}
Dans le \prettyref{tab:nombres}, on compte de un \`{a} six.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\captionsetup[table]{name=Tableau}` will only change the table name inside table environments. Outside them, the table name will be still the same as ever. So better use `\captionsetup{tablename=Tableau}` instead.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Fixed.

Comment: I have tried 
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\newrefformat{tab}{Tableau~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\captionsetup{tablename=Tableau}`
and it doesn't work. It's still showing "Table"