# How to Label a Heuristic Proof

Tags: theorems, naming

I am using `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]`  and would like to my article to read *Heuristic Proof* instead of the standard *Proof*. I am showing Ito's but not in a rigorous way. Any ideas?

```
\begin{Heuristic proof}
Since $g(x, t)$ is twice continuously-differentiable, we can apply Taylor's expansion to get 
\begin{align*}
dg(W,t) &= g(t+\Updelta t\,,\,W+\Updelta W) - g(t\,,\,W)\\
&= \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dW + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(dW)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t^2}(dt)^2+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t \partial x}(dt)(dW) + \dots\,\,(*)
\end{align*}
\end{Heuristic proof}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Heuristic proof}`?

Comment: Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's hard to say, but assuming you're using `amsthm` (and don't use `babel`), the following may work: `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Heuristic Proof)`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr

Comment: I am very new to latex and am not sure how to implement what you have both suggested into my script. I will edit the question so I have a MWE now. And yes I am using <asthm>

Comment: If you're using the `amsthm` package and its `proof` environment, just say `\begin{proof}[Heuristic proof]` since the environment uses the optional argument (if specified) for the title.

Comment: Awesome sorry for elementary questions. As i improve I will answer more questions

Comment: @KaneBlackburn TeX is a strange beast and can be very hard to get going with so don't apologise for asking elementary questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following defines a new proof-like environment in which the proof title is temporarily changed to "Heuristic Proof" (despite my own reservations of the use of the word *heuristic* in these circumstances!), implementing lockstep's idea from the comments but in such a way that the original proof environment still exists.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110653/86}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{hproof}{%
  \renewcommand{\proofname}{Heuristic Proof}\proof}{\endproof}

\begin{document}

\section{Demonstration of Proof Techniques}

\begin{thm}
Almost all primes are odd.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
There are an infinite number of primes, only one of which is even.
\end{proof}

\begin{thm}
Almost no primes are even.
\end{thm}

\begin{hproof}
Well, it's just obvious, innit?
\end{hproof}

\begin{thm}
Almost every prime is red.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
You can tell I'm running out of ideas here.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: proof name change]

Comment: Actually egreg's comment is probably easier, particularly for a one-shot use.  However, if you're going to use this several times then defining a new environment is a good way to keep it consistent.

Comment: Not sure on etiquette on here yet as this is only my second post but wanted to ask what why do you have reservations on the word heuristic. Please ignore if this is misuse of the forum.

Comment: @KaneBlackburn It's a chip on my shoulder from reading Polya's *How to solve it* book where he uses the word in an extremely precise way.  Using "heuristic" to mean "the rough idea" leaves us no word to describe something that is incredibly useful and is in danger of being forgotten: that proofs can be *figured out* and there are some very good guidelines for working out those proofs.  In short, don't take over much notice of me (but if you haven't read Polya's book, do take note that I heartily recommend it).

Comment: I share @AndrewStacey's reservations about the word (and concur in his recommending Polya. Read "Induction and Analogy in Mathematics" too). Is your proof  "heuristic" because you haven't filled in the details, but could, or "heuristic" because it's an idea for a proof that convinces you of the theorem's truth but you haven't been able to work out the formal details correctly?

Comment: In particular, for the case of "'heuristic' because you haven't filled in the details, but could", I would favour the expression "Sketch Proof".