# How to change bibliography to webography in lyx 2.0.2?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I'm writing a report with lyx 2.0.2 and I want to insert in the end a webography which is the same as bibliography but its called webography instead. So what I want basically is either to change the bibliography to webography, or if there's another way of inserting a webography in my report.

### update:

Well it's not exactly like a bibliography, the references in the webography are just urls.

### update 2:

Actually, I don't just want to change the heading of the bibliography to 'Webography' I want to change the behavior too, 'Webography' will contain references for Urls, just Urls not like bibliography author, and other stuff.
And I'm using the report class.

### update 3:

I have this in the head of the lyx document:

```
\newpage\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead {ISI}\lfoot{Shiny development}\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}\cfoot{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\makeatletter  
\let\ps@plain=\ps@empty 
\makeatother
\widowpenalty=10000 
\clubpenalty=10000 
\raggedbottom  
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

And now after trying @Torbjørn's answer, I keep having this error:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

And putting the cursor at this line:

```
\makeatother
```

And that happen even when I try to see the DVI version and when I remove the bibliography everything works fine.
By the way this is my first time writing something with lyx or latex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: So you just want to change the heading of the bibliography to 'Webography'? The general answer to this is 'see [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)' The commands there should be placed in the preamble (Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble). For a more specific answer, which documentclass are you using?

Comment: Check update 2.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post an answer soon. (By the way, users aren't usually notified about comments to posts they haven't written themselves, so to make sure someone sees a comment, write `@<username>` in it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 'webography' with the `thebibliography` environment and the `\url` command. To redefine the name, you can use the techniques described in [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993), but it seems a small change must be made due to how LyX loads packages (specifically, `babel`).

### Adding the list

Where you want to have this webography, choose the Bibliography-element from the drop-down menu in the top left. This will add a `thebibliography` environment to your document, and it will look like this:

[image]

Place the cursor right after the `key-1 [1]` inset, and choose Insert --> URL. Type a URL in the box that appears. To add a new URL to the webography, move the cursor outside the URL-inset, and hit enter. Finally, you can change the label (`key-N`) by clicking it.

### Changing the heading

LyX loads `babel` by default as far as I know, so in [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993) it is the 'With `babel`' section that is relevant, but with a small change. Add the following to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{Webography}
  }}
```

If English is not your chosen language, you have to change that.

The reason for the `\AtBeginDocument` is that when I tried this, LyX added `babel` to the very end of the preamble, the stuff you add to the preamble yourself is placed before the loading of `babel`. Therefore, `\addto\captionsenglish` is not available at the time it is used, but with `AtBeginDocument` the use is postponed until after the entire preamble.

Note that the heading will not change within LyX, but it will change in the PDF.

[image]

### Don't use `natbib`

LyX seems to behave a little silly (or maybe it's just me), so in Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, make sure that *Default (Numerical)* is selected, and not *Natbib*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but I got some errors, check update 3.

Comment: @YahyaKACEM See my update.

Comment: That did it but now I get this `(author?) [1]:` in the place where I want to put the citation, how to remove this.

Comment: @YahyaKACEM Oh, damn, sorry about that. Try with *Default (numerical)* instead of *Natbib*.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the heading of your bibliography by inserting a ERT element (Insert→TeX) right before the bibliography with the following command: `\renewcommand\refname{References }` or `\renewcommand\bibname{References}`, depending on whether you use an article or a report/book class.