# Translate paragraph environment

Tags: lyx, languages, naming

I need to translate some reserved word of paragraph environment to my own language; like Chapter, Table of Content, Example, Bibliography, and some more. How do I achieve that? I'm using LyX in Linux. Book document class.

Comment: Which language? For most languages, just go to *Document->Settings->Language*, select your *Language* from the  dropdown-box and a respective *Language package* (usually `Bable`).

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Do you want it translated in the LyX output or the PDF output or both?

Comment: Well its a local region not national language so it is not on the list

Comment: If you're not using Babel, just see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993 The relevant commands should be placed in the preamble. If you're using Babel, see the second part of [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112391/how-to-change-bibliography-to-webography-in-lyx-2-0-2).

Comment: If the comment by @TorbjørnT. solved your problem, please say so. He will post it as an answer and you can accept it. If it did not solve your problem, update your question to explain why.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. your solution works, but if I use english as my base language, in this case I'm using indonesian, I've tried to change \addto\captionsenglish{% to \addto\captionsindonesian{% but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Nur if you look at the source generated by LyX, you'll see `\documentclass[bahasa]{...`, i.e. the name of the language used by `babel` is `bahasa`, not Indonesian. `\addto\captionsbahasa` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer to this question is found in [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr), the relevant commands from that question can be added to the preamble, in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble.

There are, however, a couple of things that need to be taken into account in LyX, if `babel` is used in the document:

### Loading order

When LyX generates the complete preamble for the LaTeX file, it loads `babel` after the custom commands added by the user, in the document settings. As a result, if one adds e.g. `\addto\captionsenglish{...` it won't work, because those are commands defined by `babel`.

To circumvent this problem, one can use `\AtBeginDocument` to postpone the redefinitions to the position of `\begin{document}`, i.e. after the preamble, as mentioned in [How to change bibliography to webography in lyx 2.0.2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112391/how-to-change-bibliography-to-webography-in-lyx-2-0-2). Hence, instead of e.g.

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
 ...
}
```

use

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addto\captionsenglish{%
    ... 
}}
```

I suppose that adding `\usepackage{babel}` to the Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble before the redefinitions is another option, but then `babel` is loaded twice.

### Language name

In some cases, at least for Indonesian, the language name used in the LaTeX code is not the same as specified in the LyX document settings. When choosing *Indonesian* in the document settings, the name passed to `babel` is `bahasa`. This can be checked by looking at the complete source code generated by LyX, and checking the optional arguments for the document class, which is in the first line of code. With the default settings for the book class, and Indonesian as language, that line looks like

```
\documentclass[oneside,bahasa]{book}
```

Therefore, instead of

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addto\captionsindonesian{%
    ... 
}}
```

you need

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addto\captionsbahasa{%
    ... 
}}
```