# LYX- Change title of “Acknowledgments” in LYX

Tags: lyx, revtex

In Lyx, section Acknowledgments, I need to change the title displayed as "Acknowledgements" in the pdf. How can I do that ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Can you describe how you add this Acknowledgement, does it come from a module, or a (non-standard) document class?

Comment: I am using a package that translates in my own language. But anyway it displays "Acknowledgements" in the pdf (not under Lyx, where it is written: "remerciements". I am not asking for a way to permanently change the translation, just a way to have control on the characters sequence "Acknowledgement", to modify it in my document.

Comment: Which package? Which document class are you using? How exactly do you add these acknowledgements? We really need more details to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Lyx, I used the default package of Lyx for French language (I dont know its name), for the class it is article(revtex4), for the Aknowledgements, I simply select Acknowledgements (it appears in French) in the Environment box

Comment: No worries. Knowing the document class is sometimes necessary, and very much in this case, as it is that which defines the Acknowledgements environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change this, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble, and add

```
\renewcommand\acknowledgmentsname{Remerciements}
```

Or change `Remerciements` to whatever you like.

This is one of many such definitions made in `revtex4.cls`, in the lines 5878 to 5911 (may others as well, I haven't checked). Here you'll also find `\def\tocname{Contents}`, so to change *Contents* into something else, `\renewcommand\tocname{Something else}`. Below is a copy the above mentioned lines:

```
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
\def\notesname{Notes}
\def\partname{Part}
\def\tocname{Contents}
\def\lofname{List of Figures}
\def\lotname{List of Tables}
\def\refname{References}
\def\indexname{Index}
\def\figurename{FIG.}
\def\figuresname{Figures}%
\def\tablename{TABLE}
\def\tablesname{Tables}%
\def\abstractname{Abstract}
\def\appendixesname{Appendixes}%
\def\appendixname{Appendix}%
\def\acknowledgmentsname{Acknowledgments}
\def\journalname{??}
\def\copyrightname{??}
\def\andname{and}
\def\@pacs@name{PACS numbers: }%
\def\@keys@name{Keywords: }%
\def\ppname{pp}
\def\numbername{number}
\def\volumename{volume}
\def\Dated@name{Dated: }%
\def\Received@name{Received }%
\def\Revised@name{Revised }%
\def\Accepted@name{Accepted }%
\def\Published@name{Published }%
```

Note that for the standard classes, these are changed by `babel` (the standard language package used by LyX), and if you want to change them into something else, see [Translate paragraph environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/translate-paragraph-environment)

Comment: Thanks, I need the same for the "Contents" title: something like \renewcommand\contentsname{Contents} does not work (I get an error: "contentsname not defined").

Comment: And the same for the bibliography !

Comment: @Gilbert See my updated answer.