# LYX - change TABLE to TABLEAU

Tags: lyx, naming

I use the document class "book(more font sizes)", with French language. Tables appear as "Table" in the pdf. I tried `\renewcommand\tablename{TABLEAU}` in the preamble, but even if it does not generate an error, it does not work neither.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/translate-paragraph-environment

Comment: I tried in the preamble: \AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{new}
}  no effect, and I tried: \addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{new}
} with \usepackage{babel} before each time. It does not work, and the second option generates an error.

Comment: Replace `\captionsenglish` with `\captionsfrench`. Delete all auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: @lockstep Fantastic, it works perfectly !