# Change text in LaTeX chapter titles from "Chapter" to "chapter"

Tags: sectioning, chapters, capitalization, naming

I want to change the text displayed for each new chapter (e.g. "Chapter 1") to lower case (e.g., "chapter 1") in the `report` document class. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{chapter}`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr