# Change "chapter" to "Chapter" - How to do this using autoref?

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, labels, books, autoref

I am trying to change "chapter" to "**C**hapter" when autoreferencing the label

[image]

I have looked for a solution and some comment in this closed question [Change text in LaTeX chapter titles from "Chapter" to "chapter"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115742/change-text-in-latex-chapter-titles-from-chapter-to-chapter) suggested to use renew command

I have used "babel" as well as "renewcommand" but nothing has changed.[image]

Can someone please help? Minimum working example below.

```
%% *** Add any desired options. ***
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{chapter}
\begin{document}
       \chapter{Before We Begin}
       In \autoref{Chapter2}, we will talk about how to live a full life.
       \chapter{Begin}
       \label{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As an alternative, the package `cleferref` package has an option for capitalization: `\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}` and `\cref{Chapter2}`.

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't load the `nomencl` and `amsmath` packages twice. Nothing good is going to come from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\autoref does not capitalize initial character in sentence when referencing label in listings environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34155/autoref-does-not-capitalize-initial-character-in-sentence-when-referencing-labe)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The manual of the `hyperref` package explains how to achive this on page 17.

**Edit:** This answer assumes that you actually *want* to use the `babel` package.  If this is not the case, just redefine `\chapterautorefname` at the `\begin{document}` hook: see [Bernard’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370999/69818) for instructions on how to do this.

```
\documentclass{book}

% \usepackage{siunitx}
% \usepackage{nomencl}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{nicefrac}
% \usepackage{nomencl}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amsthm}     
% \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}%
}
\begin{document}
       \chapter{Before We Begin}
       In \autoref{Chapter2}, we will talk about how to live a full life.
       \chapter{Begin}
       \label{Chapter2}
       Live until you die\textellipsis~:-)
\end{document}
```

Here’s the output I get:

[image: Output of the code]

## Addition

Of course, the same mechanism works for other titles as well:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}%
  \def\sectionautorefname{Section}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Subsection}%
  \def\subsubsectionautorefname{Subsubsection}%
  \def\paragraphautorefname{Paragraph}%
  \def\subparagraphautorefname{Subparagraph}%
}
\begin{document}
       \chapter{Before We Begin}
       In \autoref{Chapter2}, we will talk about how to live a full life.
       \chapter{Begin}
       \label{Chapter2}
       Live until you die\textellipsis~:-)
\end{document}
```

For a complete list of the available names, see the file `hyperref.sty` at lines, say, 3220–3235.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for section also? Or is it what I think "\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\sectionautorefname{Section}%
}"

Comment: @ProcrastinationSage: See Addition.

Answer (score 11):

Whether you use babel or not, this works (no problem if you only use the English language – otherwise @Gustavo Mezzeti's answer is more appropriate):

```
\documentclass[english]{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}}%

\begin{document}

       \chapter{Before We Begin}
       In \autoref{Chapter2}, we will talk about how to live a full life.
       \chapter{Begin}
       \label{Chapter2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I bet, however, that one is going to have issues if more than one language is used (not very likely, admittedly).

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: That was my implicit hypothesis. Should I be clearer?

Comment: In general, I think it is a matter of mental order to keep distinct the two scenarios “`babel` used” vs. “`babel` not used”, and to give separate instructions for the two.  Please note the *my* implicit hypothesis, in my answer, is that the OP actually *wanted* to use `babel`, and this, reading more carefully, doesn’t seem to be the case.  So your answer is probably better: +1.

Comment: Hi is the way to capitalize "Section" and "Subsection" done in the same way?

Comment: Yes. See lines 3220-3235 in `hyperref.sty`.

Answer (score 0):

I get annoyed all the time, not just for `chapter`s, but also for `section`s. I also found using `subsection` and `subsubsection` in text would not be appealing, when it is possible to use `Chapter 1`, `Section 5`, `Section 3.1` and `Section 2.5.4`.

Add this at the beginning of your tex file:

```
\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter} 
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section} 
\let\subsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname 
\let\subsubsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
```

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]