# How to change the \see command when indexing with multind?

Tags: indexing, naming

I'm trying to change the output of `\see` in the index. The default outcome is:

> John Doe *see* Doe, John.

I'd like to add a new command or change this one to my native language. I tried to declare a `\newcommand` or to `\renewcommand` but I'm failing syntax as I keep on getting errors when *latexing* the document. (Not even dare to replicate them here.)

P.S: I guess that changing *see* to classical ways, such as *vd.* or *vide* would do the trick for most languages.

Comment: The command you have to change is `\seename`; with `babel` this is automatic.

Comment: I am using babel. And `\index{John Doe|see{Doe, John}}` results in _see_. Apparently it is not affected by Babel.

Comment: The solution in [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography" etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr) does not work for me. Maybe it is because I'm using multind package. I believe it overrides makeidx because it declares this `\def\see#1#2{{\em see\/} #1}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `multind` package is really old and didn't follow the change in `makeidx` when the explicit `see` was changed into `seename`.

You can correct this by saying

```
\renewcommand*{\see}[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}
```

after having loaded `multind`. This should adjust the compatibility with `babel`. If you need to change `\seename`, then add something like

```
\addto\captions<language>{\renewcommand{\seename}{vide}}
```

(for instance `\captionsitalian` if your language is Italian).

There are more recent packages for multiple indices: `index`, `splitidx` and `imakeidx`. I'm biased towards the last one. `;-)`

Comment: It worked. Although now it also shows the page where the index entry, which it shouldn't as it is a crossreferring index entry. Actually `\see` didn't show the page.  
P.S: I din't tried `imakeidx`. I didn't run into it when I looked for a multiple index package. As for the other two, I liked `multind` better.

Comment: @John Sorry, I typed `[1]` instead of `[2]`