# Changing style file for bibliography

Tags: natbib, naming, harvard-style

How do I change the 'plainnat' style file of `natbib` so that the title of the Bibliography is "References" and not "Bibliography"?

Note: This is required for thesis corrections and I would rather keep plainnat than change to some other format.

Comment: You don't have to use another natbib/BibTeX style for this. Redefining `\refname` will fix your problem.

Comment: See also the more generic question [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)

Comment: Thanks a million. In the end, I found that the following worked well: \usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}