# A problem with indexing (see also appearing instead of see)

Tags: indexing, amsbook

Hello I would like to add some terms that mean the same thing in the index of my thesis. For example "vector space" and "linear space". I wish this to appear as "vector space, see linear space". I'm using amsbook and for such an example I'm writing `\index{vector space|see{linear space}}`. However, it keeps on coming up as "see also" instead of "see". I don't know if this is a common problem but I couldn't find a solution anywhere on the web. Here's the code I'm using, without any chapter files - it still runs.

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Beginning of amsbook.template
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%    AMS-LaTeX v.2 driver file template for use with amsbook
%
%    Remove any commented or uncommented macros you do not use.

\documentclass{amsbook}

%    For use when working on individual chapters
%\includeonly{}

%    Include referenced packages here.
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,latexsym,amsxtra}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[thm]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}

%    For a single index; for multiple indexes, see the manual
%    "Instructions for preparation of papers and monographs:
%    AMS-LaTeX" (instr-l.pdf in the AMS-LaTeX distribution).
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{}

%    Remove any unused author tags.

%    author one information
\author{}
\address{}
\curraddr{}
\email{}
\thanks{}

%    author two information
\author{}
\address{}
\curraddr{}
\email{}
\thanks{}

\subjclass[2000]{Primary }
%    For books to be published after 1 January 2010, you may use
%    the following version:
%\subjclass[2010]{Primary }

\keywords{}

\date{}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

%    Dedication.  If the dedication is longer than a line or two,
%    remove the centering instructions and the line break.
%\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\vspace*{13.5pc}
%\begin{center}
%  Dedication text (use \\[2pt] for line break if necessary)
%\end{center}
%\cleardoublepage

%    Change page number to 6 if a dedication is present.
\setcounter{page}{4}

\tableofcontents

%    Include unnumbered chapters (preface, acknowledgments, etc.) here.
\include{}

\mainmatter

\index{Hello|see{Hi}}

%    Include main chapters here.
\include{}

\appendix
%    Include appendix "chapters" here.
\include{}

\backmatter
%    Bibliography styles amsplain or harvard are also acceptable.
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{}
%    See note above about multiple indexes.
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line into the preamble.

```
\renewcommand*{\seename}{see}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `amsbook` class has a slight different way of specifiying ‘see’ entries in the index. Here are the relevant lines

```
1314 \newcommand*\seeonlyname{see}
1315 \newcommand*\seename{see also}
1316 \newcommand*\alsoname{see also}
1317 \newcommand*\seeonly[2]{\emph{\seeonlyname} #1}
1318 \newcommand*\see[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}
1319 \newcommand*\seealso[2]{\emph{\alsoname} #1}
```

[According to Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr/82994#comment178170_82994) the definition of `\seename` was recognized as wrong when it was too late for changing it. Therefore the AMS classes added `\seeonly`.

So, if you have to submit the document to AMS, it's better to use

```
\index{Hello|seeonly{Hi}}
```

because a `\renewcommand{\seename}{see}` might be rejected by the editorial staff. For your personal use,

```
\renewcommand{\seename}{see}
```

is perfectly fine.