# How to change the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

When I am using the `\begin{thebibliography}` ... `\end{thebibliography}` environment, the 'References' appears in the translated document. How can I change this text to see something else,  for instance, 'Test', on the finished document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Try `\renewcommand*{\refname}{Test}`

Comment: The general answer: see [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)