# How can I print the table of contents multiple times in my document?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using also `titletoc` to improve how my table of contents. I would like to print the table of contents several times. How can I do it?

It does not work in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hello}
\section{Bye}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I have this code in my document, in order to have no title for the table of contents.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

PPS: `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}% Remove \tableofcontents' title/name` will not work since I am using `[french]{babel}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc); using `\printcontents`, you can replicate the ToC as many times as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\startcontents
\section{Hello}
\section{Bye}

\printcontents{}{1}{\section*{\contentsname}}

\printcontents{}{1}{\section*{\contentsname}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use [`etoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc). It provides this functionality out-of-the-box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hello}
\section{Bye}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a simple solution, but it clashes with `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother`, whose goal is to remove the title "Contents".

Comment: @Colas `\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\contentsname{}}` See [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it works !!

Comment: Useful package for writing contents several times. Does it works for listoffigures two ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for your disponibility