# How do I print the contents page on another page(s)?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1][\contentsname]{%
\section*{#1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\@starttoc{toc}
\end{multicols}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{ONE}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{1-One}

\part{TWO}
\tableofcontents % <--- empty page
\chapter{One}
\section{1-One}

\end{document}
```

How do I print the contents page on another page?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`etoc` package](//ctan.org/pkg/etoc). From the description: "The `\table­of­con­tents` com­mand may be used arbitrarily many times in the same document, while `\lo­caltable­of­con­tents` provides a 'local' table of contents."

Comment: @Werner, I'll try.

Comment: It depends on what you want specifically for `\tableofcontents` to print. You could print two duplicate `\tableofcontents`', but it seems like you want something specific to each `\part`. See [How can I print the table of contents multiple times in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179374/5764)

Comment: @Werner, please, can you look at my edited question?

Comment: Do you want the `\tableofcontents` to be the same in both cases?

Comment: @Werner, yes I want it to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`etoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoc), since it allows you to use `\tableofcontents` multiple times.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titletoc,etoc}

\makeatletter
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \let\chapter\section% Set the ToC as a \section (default is \chapter in book)
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo% Remove any header addition
    \oldtableofcontents% Regular ToC
  \end{multicols}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{ONE}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{1-One}

\part{TWO}
\tableofcontents % <--- Duplicate ToC
\chapter{One}
\section{1-One}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's working but in my actual file, I get an error like the following. Where do you suggest I look?

    \tf@toc=\write12
    \openout12 = `tmp.toc'.
    ! Missing number, treated as zero.
    <to be read again>
    \Etoc@level
    l.54 \tableofcontents
    ?
    ! Emergency stop.

Comment: @Özgür: Don't know. Perhaps delete all the auxiliary files created by (La)TeX and try again. Otherwise, you'd have to supply some code that reproduces your problem in order for anyone to solve it.

Comment: I found the problem when adding the `\usepackage{minitoc}` was having trouble. But now this package is not working for me and I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `book` class so try switching to the `memoir` class (which extends `book`) where you can use `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` as many times as you want. The manual (`> texdoc memoir`) has examples of changing the style of the ToC *et al* and also how to have a short ToC and a long one.