# How to change the word "table"/"cuadro" for "tabla" using \cref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, naming

I´m starting using `cleveref` package. I like it.

But now I´m typing in spanish and when `\cref` is pointing to a table I want that use the word "tabla" instead "cuadro", in the text.

When I type "is \cref{tab:a1}" I want obtain "is **tabla** 2" and NOT "is **cuadro** 2"

I tried with this lines

```
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
```

but this only changes the word below the table, as you can see.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla} 

La \cref{tab:1a} es bonita(beautifull)\\

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[h!]{ccc}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & label label-tab:1a \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all I think it's worth to read answer to question "¿Por qué spanish para babel dice cuadro en lugar de tabla?" (Why spanish babel says "cuadro" instead of "tabla"?) in [FAQ-CervanTeX](http://www.aq.upm.es/Departamentos/Fisica/agmartin/webpublico/latex/FAQ-CervanTeX/FAQ-CervanTeX-6.html) (FAQ from spanish users group).

And in case you still insist in changing this word, adding `es-tabla` option to `babel` will do it. With `cleveref` some more customization is needed as lockstep suggested but I think something like

```
\crefname{table}{\spanishtablename}{\spanishtablename}
```

could be better than a `hardcoded` solution.

Last comment if `spanish` is passed as option to `documentclass`, it will be automatically passed to `babel` and `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{table}{\spanishtablename}{\spanishtablename}

\begin{document}

La \cref{tab:1a} es bonita (\emph{beautifull})\\

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[h!]{ccc}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & label label-tab:1a \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if we are using polyglossia instead?

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}
```

to your example. See section 8.1.2 of the `cleveref` manual for details. Note that it is also good practice to load `cleveref` at the very end of the preamble.

Comment: is important type it after \begin{document} Thank you @lockstep

Comment: @MikaIke General formatting changes should be done in the preamble. Note that, instead of redefining `\tablename` and `\listtablename` in the document body, you should do it in the preamble using `\addto\captionsspanish`; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr

Comment: @lockstep I agree it should be in the preamble, but in my case it has no effect... on the other hand, inserting after ```\begin{document}```, as suggested by @mika-ike, does has effect. Maybe my template is running something just before ```\begin{document}``` and re-re-defining for `cuadro'. I've tried to put ```\crefname``` inside ```\AtBeginDocument```, but it also did not work. :-(

Comment: I've used ```\AfterEndPreamble{...}``` from the ```etoolbox``` package and added ```\AfterEndPreamble{\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}}```. It worked fine.  :-)