# Change format of chapter number in memoir class

Tags: sectioning, xetex, memoir, chapters

I am using XeLaTeX with the `memoir` class and Greek text and I would like to change the chapter title to be uppercase instead of lowercase

I have this

```
\chapter{Αποτελεσματικότητα του Ανταγωνιστικού Υποδείγματος}
```

and I get this

> Κεφάλαιο 1 Αποτελεσματικότητα...

Instead, I would like to get this

> ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ 1 Αποτελεσματικότητα

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the format you are using.  Do want to change the chapter number of the chapter _name_?

Comment: Memoir class defines \chaptername as {Chapter} and \chapterrefname as {Chapter-}  You can redefine them using \renewcommand* or \def.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried \renewcommand{\chaptername}{ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ} but didn't see any changes

Comment: @SofiaMouseti Is the accent suppressed when all uppercase is used?

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion in [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764), you need to add the new `\chaptername` to the `greek` captions using

```
\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{KEFALAIO}}
```

Here is a minimal example showing the adjustment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{KEFALAIO}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{abc}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, without the above approach, a delayed `\renewcommand` also suffices:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{\textKappa \textEpsilon \textPhi \textAlpha \textLambda \textAlpha \textIota \textOmicron}}
```

Comment: First solutuion did not work (i use polyglossia package because of zelatex, not babel, if that's the reason),
The alternative worked fine, thank u

Comment: @SofiaMouseti, such details are quite important to include in the original question. Along with a minimal example.