# French "Tableau" and English "Table" captions in tables in one LaTeX document

Tags: tables, captions, babel, languages

In my thesis I have french resume part, but main text is in English. I need to have in the resume French tables naming (`Tableau`) in table captions and in the main part instead of `Tableau` the English version `Table`. My idea does not work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{french}

    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{First}

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline  1& 1 \\ 
            \hline 1 &1  \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
\selectlanguage{english}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Second}

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline  1& 1 \\ 
            \hline 1 &1  \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

What is the way to solve the problem?

Comment: As you included the package `fonstspec` I assume you compile with Xelatex or LuaLatex?
In that case you should use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Localize the change to within the floating environment while also specifying the change to `\tablename`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \selectlanguage{french}
  \caption{First}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \selectlanguage{english}
  \caption{Second}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a close duplicate of [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764), but it wasn't clear that `frenchb` implies changes to `french`.