# Longtable's caption mixed with footnotes

Tags: tables, captions, footnotes, longtable

I use longtable for building tables in my text works & caption in the bottom. I like this multipage table environnement. But sometime, I see a problem : awful ! My caption is mixed with footnotes…

An exemple in my context, you can see the 7th footnote & the caption mixed :

[image]

Here, a minimal exemple code :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup[table]{name=\scshape Tableau, position=bottom}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline W&X&Y&Z\\\hline\endfirsthead
\hline W&X&Y&Z\\\hline\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\emph{suite}}\\\hline\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{4}{|r|}{\emph{suite}}\\\hline\caption[]{Test}\\\endfoot
\caption{Test}\label{tab:test}\\\endlastfoot
A\footnote{ABCD}&B&C&D\\\hline
A\footnote{\lipsum[4]}&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
```

Some solution ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Table captions belong at the top of tables, not at the bottom. Beside this the problem disappears if you remove the caption package, so its redefinitions are probably the source of the problem. You should notify the author of caption.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to find another way to rename Table to the french Tableau… This way : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214874/french-tableau-and-english-table-captions-in-tables-in-one-latex-document using `babel` & `\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{\textsc{Tableau}}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your answer satisfies my soul ;-)

Comment: So, what's the method to cite author in caption ? Exists a fonction to place that, because insert a footnote in the caption don't work… ?

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response was possible with the help of [@UlrikeFischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) comments.

Remove `caption` package is the solution. To conserve the caption's option, use the `babel` option like `captionsfrench`.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup[table]{name=\scshape Tableau, position=bottom}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} %
  \addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{\textsc{Tableau}}}% to conserve my caption style
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline W&X&Y&Z\\\hline\endfirsthead
\hline W&X&Y&Z\\\hline\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\emph{suite}}\\\hline\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{4}{|r|}{\emph{suite}}\\\hline\caption[]{Test}\\\endfoot
\caption{Test}\label{tab:test}\\\endlastfoot
A\footnote{ABCD}&B&C&D\\\hline
A\footnote{\lipsum[4]}&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&B&C&D\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
```