# Translate the \byline command output in french

Tags: french, newspaper

I would like to create a newspaper article and I found the command `\byline` to include my title and my name. The problem is that I need to publish my article in French and the command displays the English word `By`. Does anyone know how to translate this word to `Rédigé par <Written by>`? Note that I previously tried something kind of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214874/french-tableau-and-english-table-captions-in-tables-in-one-latex-document).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newspaper}

\begin{document}
\byline{Pas d'orchidées pour Miss Blandish}{Matt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike most packages that support translation by putting all strings in simple macros such as `\xxxname` this package has the English text embedded in the formatting, however the macros are quite simple, for example `\byline` is defined as

```
\newcommand\byline[2]{\begin{center} #1 \\%
            {\footnotesize\bf By \MakeUppercase{#2}} \\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
```

so in your preamble after loading the package you can do

```
\renewcommand\byline[2]{\begin{center} #1 \\%
            {\footnotesize\bf Rédigé par \MakeUppercase{#2}} \\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `By` is hard-coded in the `\byline` macro and therefore doesn't use any regional/language adaptations. Patch it to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newspaper}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\byline}{By}{Rédigé par}{}{}

\begin{document}

\byline{Pas d'orchidées pour Miss Blandish}{Matt}

\end{document}
```