# How to change Algorithm title to something else?

Tags: algorithms

when using \begin{algorithm} in latex for writing algorithms, we will have something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to have something else like "Procedure" instead of "Algorithm"?

**Edit**:

I tried something like is said in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmname}{Procedure}
```

but I get this error: algorithmname  Undifined

My code is like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\algorithmname}{Procedure}

\begin{document}

\begin{latin}
\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Building }{M}

\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography" etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993) Without a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) impossible to answer.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to use both algorithm and procedure in a manuscript?

Comment: @SibaMishra Please ask as a new question. Please be a bit more verbose as well. Thanks :-)