# Changing Appendix name revtex

Tags: appendices, revtex

I am using the `aps` journal template and appendices are added by using

```
\appendix
\section{bla bla}
```

So the result I get is:

"Appendix A: bla bla"

However I would like to know how to change the "Appendix A" for "App A" for example.

Thanks

Comment: `\renewcommand\appendixname{App}`

Comment: Close voters: I don't think the chosen duplicate is very appropriate. Even though the answer is thee, it focuses on more than just changing the appendix name, and uses the `appendix` package, which is not needed here.

Comment: Gonzalo Medina's solution is not what I am looking for, because I indeed tried it but it is not the solution.

Comment: @Eduardo Can you post small document which shows the problem. What Gonzalo suggested should work. For example if I create a minimal document with `\documentclass{revtex4-1}` and issue that `\renewcommand` the appendix name is correctly changed.  See whether this question has a better answer for you [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography" etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994)

Comment: Alan Munn, the link you added had the solution for my problem: it was a compatibility issue with the babel page. Thanks.