# Changing the heading of the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I want to change the heading before of the bibliography. In the example below there will be in the `table of contents` the name 'Literaturverzeichnis' for the bibliography, but before the bibliography itself the heading is `Literatur`. How can I change this to `Literaturverzeichnis`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url} 


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\bibliography{src/bib/Literaturverzeichnis} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994/91325) post, which solves the problem above. @Mico yes that was the point