# Change label numbering prefix

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to change the labeling of my figures from `A.1, A.2, ...` to `Abb. 1, Abb. 2, ...`, because my appendix chapter is already labeled with A and this causes some confusion (whether `A.1` is meaning the first section of the appendix or the first image). 
 
I know I can change the label caption like this:

```
\addto\captionsngerman{
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}    
}
```

from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993), but this isn't what I want, because it just changes `Abbildung A.1` to `Abb. A.1`. How can I change the prefix of the number?

Comment: what is the class you use?

Comment: I'm using `babel` with `ngerman`, `graphicx` and `subfigure` but I don't know if this is what you mean

Comment: 1) I mean `\documentclass{....}` 2) how do you want figure B.1 B.2 ... and C.1 C.2 to appear ?

Comment: i use a custom one, `\documentclass[german]{tex/ttthesis}` (Thomas Thüm - Template for Theses from [here](https://bitbucket.org/tthuem/thesistemplate/src/f8bb46e9d988?at=default)). I didn't know I could get B or C, what results in a change of the prefix? i thought it's A because the word ist `Abbildung`

Comment: no, A is for first chapter in appendix the 2 nd will be B ...

Comment: oh, ok... is there any way to change this behaviour so that my figures get labeled independent from the chapter?

Comment: try `\renewcommand\thefigure{Abb. \arabic{figure}}`

Comment: without the `Abb.` it's fine, because this is still put in front by `\figurename` - thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class used here is based on `book.cls` weach define `figure` by

```
\newcounter{figure}[chapter]
```

so it will be reset with chapter. To make it independent of chapter we use `chngcntr` package and its `\counterwithout` command.

Exemple: here we use itonly for appendix figure. If we want this for all document we use `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` in the preambl.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bla}
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\appendix

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bla}
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{1cm}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```