# Change the bibliography name scrartcl class

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script, naming

I am writing a `scrartcl` document using `\begin{thebibliography}`. The title of the bibliography is displayed automatically and it is "References". Can I change it to "Biography"?

I know that the command `\bibname` don't work in article class.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I suppose you mean to rename it as ‘Bibliography’?

Comment: See [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)/ for the answer to most such questions. In particular see the answer by Kurt, which deals with KOMA script classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the bibliography in the standard `article` class is defined by the `\refname` command, not the `\bibname` command (which is used by `report` and `book` classes).

Thus

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
```

changes "References" to "Bibliography".

Comment: With babel one should add the definition to the babel switch.

Comment: There are KOMA-Script commands to define or to change language  dependent names like `\refname`.  If you use  `\defcaptionname{english}{\refname}{Bibliography}`, it will also work with `babel` and `polyglossia` if language `english` is active.