# Rename bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I want to change the bibliography title 'Literatur' in 'Literaturverzeichnis', but it doesn't work with `\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{greenwade93}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use

```
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
```

cf. [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr/83021#83021), and add it after `\usepackage[..]{biblatex}`, it seems to work.

You could also do

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=Literaturverzeichnis]
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis} 
\begin{document}
\cite{greenwade93}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

%alternative
%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you could use `\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{references = {Literaturverzeichnis},}` or switch to `abbreviate=false` (works for (n)German because "Literatur" is the short form and "Literaturverzeichnis" the long). Of course the latter will change other things as well.