# Table of contents not Contents!

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

How do I write Table of Contents and not Contents in my project work? I need help on this!

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered before:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}
```

Comment: Unless you're using `babel`, see the answer you linked to, and the more general http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/