# modifying \contentsname has no effect

Tags: table-of-contents

If been trying to change the name of my table of contents. I've put this in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
```

I also tried to put it after the `\tableofcontents` command, but both times nothing is happening. I don't get an error or something, but the name isn't changed. Can someone help me out?

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimal working example that compiles, is as small as possible and demonstrates your problem. The solution depends on your documentclass and where you put this line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you use? (If the macro `\contentsname` is defined at all, it'll be defined in the document class file.) Please also be more specific as to what exactly "nothing is happening" means. What is currently typeset at the top of the table of contents?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) in addition to Andrews comment, a macro like `\contentsname` is often controlled by the `babel` package, so it has to be changed in a very specific manner

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/. I don't know your setup, but there you'll find information specific to various documentclasses, and for documents using `babel`/`polyglossia`, as @daleif mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for responding. With 'nothing is happening' I mean that the command I've put in doesn't change the name. This is my working example: 
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage(float)
\usepackage(microtype)
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}

Comment: And I don't use a babel package

Comment: Please add code examples to your question instead of comments, comments are not really suited for blocks of code. I added your snippet, and replaced the `()` for the `\usepackage` lines with `{}` (assume it was a typo). Are you really adding the `\renewcommand` *after* `\tableofcontents`? If so, move it to *before* `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem with the code snippet you show is that you're changing the definition of `\contentsname` *after* it has been used, so the redefinition naturally doesn't have any effect.

Hence, instead of

```
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}
```

you need

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents
```

However, you say that you've added the `\renewcommand` to the preamble. If you have the same version of `wlscirep.cls` as is found on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns#.WE0d5BIxCV5), you *are* in fact using `babel`, as the class contains the line

```
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
```

When you do the redefinition *after* `\begin{document}`, it still works. But if you want the redefinition to be in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`), you need

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
 \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the command in this way.

```
 \begin{document}
 \author{Namef}
  \title{Title of Thesis}
  \date{December 2016}
   \frontmatter

    \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}

     \maketitle
      \tableofcontents
```