# How can I rename the 'List of Publications' section in the CurVe document class?

Tags: bibliographies, curve-class

I'm using the CurVe document class. Here is a minimal working example:

fav_book.tex:

```
\begin{rubric}{My Favourite Book}

 This is my favourite book~\cite{fav}
\end{rubric}
```

biblography.tex:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

 \bibitem{fav} Thor, A.U., 2017. \textit{Best book ever}. 1st ed. London: Best Publishers.

\end{thebibliography}
```

CV.tex:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{curve}
\begin{document}
\makerubric{fav_book}
\makerubric{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

This comes out looking like this:

[image: mwe_ListofPubs]

How can I rename 'List of Publications' to 'References' (because in my case, I don't wish it to be my own publications).

I may be looking for '[name macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)' depending on how CurVe works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the CurVe class documentation:

> The `\listpubname` macro takes one mandatory argument which redefines the title
>   of the bibliographic section (when you use the provided bibliography support). By
>   default, “List of Publications” is used in English. Note that for compatibility with
>   the multibbl and multibib packages, CurVe honors the existence of `\bibname` or
>   `\refname` macros prior to `\listpubname` for deciding which title to give to the
>   bibliographic rubric.