# I want to change Ringkasan into Abstrak

Tags: babel, languages, abstract

I'm sorry for always asking. I have another problem. I want to change the abstract title "Ringkasan" into "Abstrak" when I'm using `[bahasa]{babel}`. How to do that?

Comment: `\addto\captionsbahasa{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstrak}}` in the preamble.

Comment: The general answer to questions like this is to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/. If the method described there doesn't work, then we'd need more info about your setup.