# How to translate the automatic words such as: table, figure, appendix, reference, etc

Tags: babel, languages, mdpi

I'm using the template MDPI (Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute - http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex) and I'm writing the article in Portuguese, how can I translate the automatic words such as: table, figure, appendix, references, etc.?

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper,brazil]{mdpi} 

\usepackage[brazil,USenglish]{babel}


\abstract{...}

\keyword{...}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apêndice}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumo}
.
.
.
\abbreviations{}

\externalbibliography{yes}

\bibliography{mybib}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

The renewcommand works for the tables, figures and appendix, but didn't work in the case of the abstract, keywords, abbreviations and references.

Comment: Did you try something like `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` inside your preambel?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography”, “Appendix”, etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/2693). Can you also provide a link to the document class?

Comment: These is the link with the template: http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex

Comment: I wonder if you really need writing in Portuguese, though, because it seems MDPI only publishes in English, or if you just want to achieve/adapt/use the look-and-feel of those classes, which isn't that great anyway.

Comment: I need to use the look.

Comment: So you want to get something that looks like a pulished article, but isn't? Really, not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the order of the `babel` package:

```
\usepackage[USenglish,brazil]{babel}
```

`babel` uses the last language as its default.