# Make references in overleaf?

Tags: bibliographies, sections-paragraphs

My code is something like this:

```
\newpage
\section{Referências Bibliográficas}
\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}
```

I get something like this:
[image: I have this]

What I want to get is something like this:
[image: I want this]

What should I do?

Comment: Usually, you load babel which takes care of the translation.

Comment: [tag:cross-referencing] is not meant for literature references, the correct one is  [tag:bibliographies]

Answer (score 3):

Just use `\renewcommand{\refname}{Referências Bibliográficas}` for class `article` or `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referências Bibliográficas}` for class `report`, `book`.  That command renames the heading for the bibliography and you can delete your used command `\section{Referências Bibliográficas}`.

See the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referências Bibliográficas} % bibname for report,book


\begin{document}

Text~\cite{adams} % citing one bib entry 
\nocite{*}   % all not cited bib entrys are shown in bibliography ...
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use file created by filecontents ...

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

What excact you need depends on your code you did not show. Please have a look to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr) to get more informations ...

## EDIT:

Following the comments one (dirty) way can be:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\refname}{} % bibname for report,book


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Text~\cite{adams} % citing one bib entry 
\nocite{*}   % all not cited bib entrys are shown in bibliography ...

\section{Referências Bibliográficas}
\vspace{-1cm}

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use file created by filecontents ...

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: For me, this is the very same answer once again.

Comment: Now it works!!! Thanks a lot! But now I have a little problem, I have a big space between the title and the first reference...