# reducing the spacing between bib items

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, fontsize

I'm using the following codes:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
     %------------------------------------------------------------
      \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
       \usepackage{color}
        \usepackage{url}                    
        %------------------------------------------------------------
         \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
         \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
       %----------------------------------------------------------
      \usepackage{geometry}
     \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
    % ------------------------------------------------------------
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
     \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
     \newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
     \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
   \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
  \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
  \newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
  \numberwithin{equation}{section}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}
    \date{}
    \begin{document}
    \section{1}
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}

    \bibitem{26}{W. Arendt, C.J.K. Batty, M. Hieber, and F. Neubrander:} 
    {Vector-Valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems,} Monographs in 
     Mathematics, 2001.

      \bibitem{4}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} 
       {Outgrowths of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 
         51-68.

     \end{thebibliography}
         %---------------------------------
     \end{document}
```

I have two questions:

Why we write the number 9 in `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`?

Is there any way to reduce the spacing between bib items? And How to reduce the size of the word References?

Comment: For the future: Please do not ask multiple questions in one questions.

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, you have to look at how the `thebibliography` environment is defined. Here's the definition from [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co) (it's similar to what you'll find in [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co)):

```
 1: \newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 2:      {\section*{\refname}%
 3:       \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
 4:       \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
 5:            {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
 6:             \leftmargin\labelwidth
 7:             \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 8:             \@openbib@code
 9:             \usecounter{enumiv}%
10:             \let\p@enumiv\@empty
11:             \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
12:       \sloppy
13:       \clubpenalty4000
14:       \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
15:       \widowpenalty4000%
16:       \sfcode`\.\@m}
17:      {\def\@noitemerr
18:        {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
19:       \endlist}
```

For reference, I've numbered the lines. Here's some explanatory details:

- Line 1 starts by defining the `thebibliography` environment to take a single, mandatory argument. So, you'll have to call it with `\begin{thebibliography}{<something>}` rather than just `\begin{thebibliography}`.
- Line 2 sets the bibliography as a `\section*` using the title `\refname`. If you want to change this, you can add `\renewcommand{\refname}{My BiBLioGRaPHy}` somewhere before `\begin{thebibliography}{.}`. `book` and `report` uses `\bibname`. See [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764)
- Line 3 updates the running headers, both left and right headers are set to the uppercase version of whatever is in `\refname`.
- Lines 4-11 starts a `\list`. Yes, the bibliography is set as a list, so all list-related changes can be applied to the bibliography if you wish to change the formatting.

  `\list` takes 2 mandatory arguments. The first is set in line 4: `\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}`. This defines how the "label" for each `\bibitem` will be set. Specifically, every `\bibitem` sets an item label, and this label will be `\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}`, which translates to an arabic representation of the `enumiv` counter (the fourth level of an `enumerate` environment), boxed using `\@biblabel` (the default definition for this is to set its argument inside `[`..`]`).

  So, `\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}` is similar to an output of `[<num>]`, where `<num>` increases with every `\bibitem`.

  Line 5 sets the `\labelwidth` to the width of `\@biblabel{#1}` where `#1` is the argument you supplied to the `thebibliography` environment. This answers your question about the argument for `thebibliography` - it defines the width of the labels within the environment. So, if you plan on having less than 10 bibliography elements, then you can use `\begin{thebibliography}{0}` (or `x`, some single-letter element). If you have more items but fewer than 100, you can use `\begin{thebibliography}{00}`, or `\begin{thebibliography}{000}` for more items but fewer than 1000, *etc*.

  Lines 6-8 sets up horizontal margins for the list environment, with `\@openbib@code` usually being empty.

  Line 9 identifies the counter to be used with each enumerated `\bibitem`. In this case, it'll be `enumiv` (the fourth level of an `enumerate` environment). It's assumed that this counter is rarely used at that level, especially when setting a bibliography. It's unlikely that you'll set a bibliography when nested three levels into other lists.

  Line 10 removes any `p`refix for the `enumiv` counter (since nested `enumerate`s typically add their hierarchy to the enumeration).

  Line 11 updates the representation of the counter - `\theenumiv` - to be arabic.
- Lines 12-16 updates penalties and paragraph formatting parameters, since bibliographies do not contain your average textual content. It usually contains names (with unknown hyphenation patterns), URLs, cities, and many more oddities. These penalty updates allows for some flexibility to set things that might be a bit `\sloppy` otherwise.
- Lines 17-19 ends off the `thebibliography` environment (the definition of `\end{thebibliography}`) and does two things. The first is to update the way an error is reported if you do not have any `\bibitem`s in your `thebibliography` (lines 17-18) and the last is to close the `list` environment that was opened during `\begin{thebibliography}` in line 4.

---

Knowing that `thebibliography` is just a `\list`, adjustment of the vertical spacing between items is achieved by changing the value of `\itemsep` (see section **55.2 Vertical Spacing (skips)** (p 285) of [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf); something like `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` would remove all the vertical space between items.

A slightly cleaner approach would be to update this within the preamble, as in this example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@openbib@code{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{0}

  \bibitem{abhn2001}
  W. Arendt, C.J.K. Batty, M. Hieber, and F. Neubrander: 
  Vector-Valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems, Monographs in 
  Mathematics, 2001.

  \bibitem{agg2006}
  W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:
  Outgrowths of Hardy's inequality, Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp.\ 
  51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here is the same bibliography with an `\itemsep` of `1cm` using `\begin{thebibliography}{000}`:

[image]

Bigger spacing between elements, and a wider label.

---

Changing the size of the bibliography title can be achieved by setting it to something other than a `\section*`. Perhaps, say, a `\subsection*`. The following example highlights that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section}{\subsection}{}{}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@openbib@code{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{\refname}
\begin{thebibliography}{0}

  \bibitem{abhn2001}
  W.\ Arendt, C.J.K.\ Batty, M.\ Hieber, and F.\ Neubrander: 
  Vector-Valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems, Monographs in 
  Mathematics, 2001.

  \bibitem{agg2006}
  W.\ Arendt, J.R.\ Goldstein, and J.A.\ Goldstein:
  Outgrowths of Hardy's inequality, Contemp.\ Math.\ 412 (2006), pp.\ 
  51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what do you mean by `\begin{thebibliography}{0}` why you don't write `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`? Thanks

Comment: @Student: What is provided in the argument for the `thebibliography` environment doesn't have much meaning other than being used to calculate the label width of the `\bibitem`s. I used `\begin{thebibliography}{0}` because I had fewer than 10 items in the bibliography, therefore only needed a label width of a single character - `0`.

Answer (score 2):

To control the spacing between the entries, you can set `\setlength{\itemsep}{3cm}` (or whatever value you like).

The `9` means that the width of the digit 9 is reserved for the width of the numbers in front of your bib entries. If you have less than 10 entries, this is fine, if you have 10 or more entries, write `99` or `999` for more than 100 and so on.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\setlength{\itemsep}{3cm}

\bibitem{26}{W. Arendt, C.J.K. Batty, M. Hieber, and F. Neubrander:} 
{Vector-Valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems,} Monographs in 
Mathematics, 2001.

\bibitem{4}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} 
{Outgrowths of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 
 51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```