# Rename Document Sections in "Report" Class

Tags: report

Is there a way in the `report` class to change the name of a document header?  For example, change `\chapter{Test Chapter}` from

```
Chapter 1
Test Chapter
```

to

```
Part 1
Test Chapter
```

I don't want to use `\part`, just to change the name applied to the `\chapter` command.

Example Input:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
Test text
\end{document}
```

Expected Output:

```
Part 1
Test Chapter

Test text
```

Thanks!

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Flobbel}` If you use `babel` or `polyglossia` you may need to make sure that the language-specific definitions don't overwrite this: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Flobbel}}` if your language is `ngerman`

Comment: Perfect!  That worked great!

Comment: So I guess this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864