# Listings in another language

Tags: listings

I'm using the babel package along with the greek language and I want to insert a List of Listings in my document.

I used

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Κατάλογος Αλγορίθμων}
\lstlistoflistings
\cleardoublepage
```

and the output is
[image: output]

I don't care about the listings caption not showing up correctly, but I want to change the title "Λιστινγς" to something else like "Κατάλογος Αλγορίθμων" (which translates to "Table of algorithms").

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/105447 ?

Answer (score 1):

As @gusbrs stated, according to this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr) the solution is:

```
\addto\captionsgreek{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Κατάλογος Αλγορίθμων}%
}
```