# Change the Bibliography name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using a refsection as I want my bibliography to appear per section. Following is the MWE. I would like the title of my bibliography to be 'References' in chapter 1 (as it is now). But for chapter 2, I want the title of bibliography to be 'Conference Proceedings'.

Can you please help.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,style=phys,%
  articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
  chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false,%
  refsection=chapter,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}

\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the normal/default name of the bibliography/references section, you'll want to have a look at [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864).

If, on the other hand, you want to retain the normal headings for some `\printbibliography`s and change the heading only for others, you should have a look at the `title` option to `\printbibliography`. With the `heading` option you can suppress the title completely.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys,%
  articletitle=false, biblabel=brackets,%
  chaptertitle=false, pageranges=false,%
  refsection=chapter,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}
% default heading uses \refname filled with the bibstring 'references'
% or \bibname filled with bibstring 'bibliography' depending on the
% document class and heading level
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
% explicit different title given with title
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Conference Proceedings}]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
% no heading at all
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: The three chapters of the MWE side-by-side: The first chapter's bib is titled "References", the second bib "Conference Proceedings", the third bib has no heading.]

Note how I changed `\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize}` before every invocation of `\printbibliography` (which would be equivalent to `\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}` once in the preamble) to the more idiomatic `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}`. Furthermore `style=numeric-comp,style=phys,` is equivalent to the shorter and less confusing `style=phys,`, so I changed that as well.

Comment: how can I add the title of the publication in one of the lists of references and have no title in other lists?

Comment: @Rouge With `heading=none` you can completely suppress any title, if that is what you are after.

Comment: @ moewe by title I mean the title of the articles, for e.g. "Impact of electrodes on the extraction of shift current from a ferroelectric semiconductor SbSI ". I want the biblio in chapter 1 and 3 to show the titles of the articles. But no titles in chapter 2 and 4. Can you please help.

Comment: @Rouge That would be a new question. I haven't had a closer look at your other question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463014/35864, but I assume that is about that already, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. It is about that. However, the answer of gusbrs is not working for me. It would be great if you can help.

Comment: @Rouge Sure, I'll have a look.

Comment: what shall i do if i want no heading for the bibliography section?

Comment: @Rouge Does `heading=none` as in the third chapter in the example not help for that?