# How to hide/show Publication Title in per chapter bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using biber and refsections to make my bibliography per chapter.

For one chapter, I would like my bibliography to show the title of the publication, whereas for rest of the chapters I do not want the title to show up in the bibliography list. How can I do that?

In my actual code, the preamble has following definition for biblatex package:

```
\usepackage[
hyperref=auto,  
backend=biber,
sorting = none, % to have references appear as they are cited
style=numeric-comp,
style=phys,%
articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
chaptertitle=false,%
]{biblatex}
```

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,style=phys,%
  articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
  chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false,%
  refsection=chapter,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}

\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`biblatex-phys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys)' way of suppressing the titles of `@article` entries with `articletitle` is ultimately [implemented](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-phys/blob/8491ac1373915cbe06d031076f36671aac5ba9dd/phys.bbx#L97-L101) with a simple toggle called [`bbx:articletitle`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-phys/blob/8491ac1373915cbe06d031076f36671aac5ba9dd/phys.bbx#L17-L22). If the toggle is *true*, the title is printed; if it is *false* the title is suppressed.

We can simple switch the toggle to *true* in an `\AtNextBibliography` hook before the bibliography that should have titles. All other bibliographies will stick with the global default *false* that you set in the loading options in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys,
  articletitle=false, biblabel=brackets,
  chaptertitle=false, pageranges=false,
  refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\AtNextBibliography{\toggletrue{bbx:articletitle}}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: Chapter 1: Bibliography *without* article titles]
[image: Chapter 2: Bibliography *with* article titles]

As in [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463005/35864), please note that I changed `\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize}` before every invocation of `\printbibliography` (which would be equivalent to `\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}` once in the preamble) to the more idiomatic `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}`. Furthermore `style=numeric-comp,style=phys,` is equivalent to the shorter and less confusing `style=phys,`, so I changed that as well.