# nomencl doesn't renew nomname with russian language

Tags: nomencl

I'm trying to renew `\nomname` in `nomencl` package with russian language, but it still default value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Список обозначений}

\begin{document}
    \mbox{}

    \nomenclature{$c$}{Скорость света в ваккууме}
    \nomenclature{$h$}{Постоянная Планка}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\nomname}{Список обозначений}}` work? Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864

Comment: Yes, it works great!