# Classicthesis-Styled CV: Change Publications to References

Tags: cross-referencing, classicthesis, cv

I am using `classicthesis` Styled CV, and am trying to change "Publications" to "References". Does anyone know how to change this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, documents based on style `classicthesis` are usually based on class `scrartcl`.

So you can use command

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{References}
```

to get the wished heading.

Please next time add an MWE (see [what is a MWE?)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to make it easier to help you without guessing ...

Please hava a look to question [how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr) ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I still have difficulties. I have also tried

`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\refname{References}}`

but it is still not working.
I am writing down my preamble:

`\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\date{}`.

Comment: It is working. I made a mistake of putting a line \end{cv} after the bibliography.