# Change language option with Babel not working. OVERLEAF template

Tags: babel

I used a Template from OVERLEAF to write a document. 
I am using

```
\documentclass[spanish,oneside,12pt]{Classes/RoboticsLaTeX}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-tabla]{babel}
```

but it wont change the name of the chapters. I intend it to change "Chapter n" to "Capítulo n". It should also change "List of Figures" to "Lista de Figuras"

Do you know how to change all these titles?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The document class I am using is \documentclass[spanish,oneside,12pt]{Classes/RoboticsLaTeX}, maybe there is anothe documenclass that works for Master Thesis as well

Comment: Can you please add an link to that template?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr ?